# When I press back on my UInavigation bar while a webview is loading, my app crashes...?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, loading, back

I have a view with a navigation bar in my iphone app.  The navigation bar has a back button on it to go the the previous view.  Within the view is a webview.  If the webview is loading while the user presses the back button on the navigation bar, the app crashes with the error message:

```
[WebViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I am assuming that I release some things when the view unloads.  I believe my viewWillDisapear method takes care of stopping the webview from loading... But still, when I press back while the view is not fully loaded, it crashes.

It seems to happen when I let the view finish loading about 20% of the time - and only if I press the back button really quickly after the page finishes loading.

Here is the code that I believe runs during this shinanigans....:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]]];
    [addressBar setText:url];
}
```

and then when the webview is loading:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

if (first) {
   //mtns is a uiimageview
    mtns.alpha = .8;
    first = NO;
}
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

and after a suggestion, I added this method:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
}
```

I don't know why it is crashing so I am sort of at a loss

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 8):

You could override `-viewWillDisappear:` to stop the UIWebView from loading and set the delegate to nil.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of before the execution code that you have written in  viewwillDisapper application crashes.try to put breakpoint and check whether viewwillDisapper method is called or not.If its not called then write the code that mark has suggested before the application navigates to second view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure to set the **delegate** property of the web view to nil before it goes away. Do this both in your **dealloc** and **viewDidUnload** methods, since **viewDidUnload is not always called before dealloc**. What’s happening is that after your view controller is deallocated, the web view still has a reference to its address, and is trying to send it a message (-respondsToSelector:).

```
- (void)dealloc {
    webView.delegate = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    webView.delegate = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```